# Changed image ratio is not applied for tableView cell on first load in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I have tableview I am displaying image in it with SDWebImage pod. I am changing the dimension after download of the image it's working good but after first load, in initial loading the changed dimension are not applied. Here is my code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reusableCellId) as? FeedTableViewCell
        if feedTableData.count > indexPath.row {
            let rowData = feedTableData[indexPath.row]
            
            
            cell?.feedImage?.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: rowData.poster), completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in 
                if let image = image {
                    //cell?.configure(image: image)
                    
                    let hRatio = image.size.height / image.size.width
                    let newImageHeight = hRatio * UIScreen.main.bounds.width
                    cell?.imageHeightContarint?.constant = newImageHeight
                    cell?.feedImage?.image = image
                    cell?.feedImage?.setNeedsLayout()
                    cell?.feedImage?.layoutIfNeeded()

                }
                
        })
            
            //cell?.fillInfo(info: rowData)
        }
        return cell ?? UITableViewCell()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When a table view lays out its rows/cells...

- is `heightForRowAt indexPath` implemented?

  - use that value
- else, is `tableView.rowHeight` set to a specific value?

  - use that value
- else, ask the cell for its height (based on its constraints and data)

  - use that value

Once the table is displayed, it **no longer modifies its row heights**.

So, if your code *changes* the content of the cell in a way that its height will change, we have to inform the controller and let it re-layout the cell(s).

For your case - using `sd_setImage(...)` from (I'm assuming) [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage), you need to inform the controller at the end of your completion block.

So:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reusableCellId) as? FeedTableViewCell
    if feedTableData.count > indexPath.row {
        let rowData = feedTableData[indexPath.row]
        
        cell?.feedImage?.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: rowData.poster), completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in
            if let image = image {
                //cell?.configure(image: image)
                
                let hRatio = image.size.height / image.size.width
                let newImageHeight = hRatio * UIScreen.main.bounds.width
                cell?.imageHeightContarint?.constant = newImageHeight
                cell?.feedImage?.image = image

                // you shouldn't need either of these lines
                //cell?.feedImage?.setNeedsLayout()
                //cell?.feedImage?.layoutIfNeeded()

                // add this line - it will cause the table view to
                //  re-calculate the row heights
                tableView.performBatchUpdates(nil)
                
            }
            
        })
        
        //cell?.fillInfo(info: rowData)
    }
    return cell ?? UITableViewCell()
}
```

As a side note, you're doing several things incorrectly with your cell dequeueing (to get rid of all those `?`), and you should use `[weak self]`  in your completion block ... but that information can be found by researching the proper approaches.